# Is codeigniter 3 safe enough to start project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, frameworks

First of all I should remind you I have read some links and done some research and looked at some old questions but I still have a question.

I want to start a project with codeigniter 3 but I have heard that codeigniter is not secure enough!

I don't know if it is correct or not, so I started researching about it but now I still don't know. Should I start my project with codeigniter or not! I don't know how to work with any other frameworks and I don't have enough time so I want to ask you if I should start my project by codeigniter. Is it really unsafe? and what shall I do to make it secure or is it possible or not?

I know that the security depends on programmer but I want to be sure that codeigniter does not have a big security bug that any hacker can hack my project and destroy it.

what would you do ?

I'm really afraid

Comment: Codeigniter also uses CSRF and for a user login I would look at ion_auth as a plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Codeigniter is a framework and is not solely responsible for your site's security. Your site's security is truely determined by the code you write with CodeIgniter. An empty CodeIgniter install is very, very secure. Simply because it's not using any user input or operating with any database.

**Codeigniter 3 is no longer in beta and has a stable release available here:** https://codeigniter.com/download

If your concern is security, make sure you develop the site with security best practices. Typically, if a site is hacked, it's due to a lazy developer and not the framework they were developing with.

Answer (score 1):

along with security are all the million other things that can go wrong on the server or "cloud" which is hosting your application. so -- even if its just you working on the app -- become comfortable with git and version control. i just discovered the phpstorm application for developing php code and it has version control built in, along with other features that makes it easier to maintain **more then one working copy** of your application.

otherwise to your question - Codeigniter is being actively maintained, has a friendly community, and the code is very fast & stable in production.